# Как вывести массив в div

Tags: javascript

При нажатие на кнопку должна произойти функция которая будет выводить значение input в массив, а массив в div. Как вывести массив в div ?

```
let input = document.querySelector('.input');
let out = document.querySelector('.out');  //div
let btn = document.querySelector('#btn');  //button

//массив в который будет выводить 
let mass = [];  

btn.onclick = function func1() {
  let val = input.value; 
  out.innerHTML += mass.push(val);
}
```

При выводе out получяется число елеметов в массиве, то-есть одно нажатие вывод '1', два нажатия вывод '2'. Как вывести не количество елементов а значение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант 1:

```
let mass = [];  

btn.onclick = () => {
  let val = input.value; 
  mass.push(val);
  out.innerHTML += val
}
```

Вариант 2:

```
let mass = [];  

btn.onclick = () => {
  mass.push(input.value);
  out.innerHTML = mass.join('<br/>')
}
```